# Will Starman/Roadster pass particularly close to any asteroids in the next few years?

Tags: tesla-roadster, conjunction

Given what's known about Starman/Roadster's orbit (2018-017A, 43205) have there been, or are there any future predicted close passes to asteroids or comets (or anything) in the next few years?

These may not be visually verifiable, but orbital mechanics being what it is, there could still be predicted conjunctions.

---

Using the information from [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/25151/7982) the last actual sighting of Roadster seems to be in [DASO circular 0567](https://www.minorplanetcenter.net/iau/DASO/000000/DASO_000567.txt) on 2018/02/22.35017 but with so many sightings from launch until then, there must be a pretty good model for it's orbit.

**edit:** [This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/29958/12102) suggests that the last measurement was several weeks later.