# Determine if two orbits cross paths

Tags: orbit, debris, collision-avoidance, space-track, poliastro

I'm trying to determine which orbital object will have the most close calls with another object. I've gotten the full TLE catalog from Space-Track.org, and using poliastro python package have converted them all into Orbit objects so I have all the relevant orbital data, but now I'm at a loss for how to compare orbits with each other to see if they get close enough (ignoring actual position, just wondering how close in km the orbital paths get). I believe this will take a little over 171 million calculations, but I have time to let it run for a while. Thanks!

Comment: What distance do you consider “close”?  If that’s like 10 km, you can simplify the problem a lot.

Comment: [See this Q&A](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29946/9060) for some relevant discussion.

Comment: For this initial pass I'd be happy with a "within 20 km" metric, and then deal with fine tuning it once I have those results.